# How does this Java code instantiate an abstract class?

Tags: java, class, syntax, instantiation, abstract

I am making changes to a Java class of ours, and I noticed the following line of code:

```
OurClass<OurInterface1> ourClass = new OurClass<OurInterface1>() {};
```

What I find strange about that line is that `OurClass` is an abstract class - here's the definition of `OurClass`:

```
public abstract class OurClass<T extends OurInterface1> implements OurInterface2<T>
```

When I remove the `{}` at the end of the line, Eclipse tells me `Cannot instantiate the type OurClass<OurInterface1>`, but when I put the `{}` back, everything is OK.

How does `{}` allow you to instantiate an abstract class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the `{}` introduces the syntax for an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The new operator
> - The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of parentheses, as in this example.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

You are declaring an anonymous inner class that subclasses `OurClass`.  The body of this class is empty: `{}`.  This anonymous inner class is not `abstract`, so you are able to instantiate it.

When you remove the `{}`, the compiler thinks that you are directly instantiating `OurClass`, an `abstract` class, so it disallows it.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually extend and override methods on the fly when you instantiate off an interface or extendible class. This is called an anonymous inner class.

What you did in your example is create an anonymous inner class, but it had no effect because you didn't override anything. You could have put overridden methods in those curly brackets `{}`.

```
OurClass<OurInterface1> ourClass = new OurClass<OurInterface1>() {};
```

A commonly applied use of anonymous inner class is on the `Runnable` interface, which defines a single void `run()` method. You can implicitly instantiate an object that implements `Runnable` and override `run()` on the fly.

```
Runnable someTask = new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("Running a task!");
    }
};
```

Anonymous inner classes are disliked by a lot of developers because they are pretty verbose. Fortunately in Java 8, you can use lambda expressions to replace most anonymous inner classes that implement a single method. The compiler infers the anonymous inner class for you basically, allowing you to write the code more concisely.

```
Runnable someTask = () -> System.out.println("Running a task!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The block after the call to the `new` operator (`new OurClass<OurInterface1>() {}`) is infact creating an instance of an anonymous class which extends `OutClass`.

Since this class is no longer `abstract`, there's no problem to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class without implementing the abstract functions within the class. This is usually done by instatiating abstract classes with implemented class.
Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

In your case, the {} used after the instantiation allows you to implement any of the abstract functions in the abstract class.

For example,

Consider

```
public abstract class  DummyClass {
 abstract void test() ;
```

}

is the abstract class with a abstract function.

The class can be initiated by:

```
DummyClass d = new DummyClass(){
       void test(){
             //test() implementation here 
        }
    } ;
```

Hope this helps! :)